# Negative number in parentheses and comma in math mode

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to create a sample financial statement. For the sake of demonstration purposes, here's my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}    
    Using fpeval: 1,000 - 2,000 = $\num[group-separator={,}]{\fpeval{1000 - 2000}}$.
    
    Using comma in inline math environment (for demon purposes): $1,000$
    
    text: 1,000
    
    Desired result: (1,000)
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Current output]

I tried using the `\num` command with the `group-separator`, but to no avail. The group separator won't appear. Is there a way to use some commands in the math environment to get the desired result as shown in "Desired result"? I would like to get the parentheses to appear when the number is negative (and not to appear when it's nonnegative), and when I put the comma in the math environment, there would be extra whitespace after the comma.

Update: besides the answers provided, I managed to use the `bracket-negative-numbers` option for `siunitx`.

Comment: You can type `$1{,}000$` or use the [`siunitx` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

Comment: I am trying to input the thousands separator when I use `fpeval`. By the way, I just updated my question.

Comment: As a tangent, I would _not_ use "demon" as an abbreviation of "demonstration."

Comment: @AndrewRay Oops, typo! Sorry about this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `group-minumum-digits` to `4`: the standard setting is `5`. For example

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}
\begin{document}    
    Using \textsf{siunitx}: $\num{1000} - \num{2000} =
      \num[evaluate-expression]{1000 - 2000}$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you need more predefined parameters, like

1. You can use `\usepackage[round-mode=places,group-separator={,},output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}` in your preamble, and use `\num{\fpeval{1000 - 2000}}` if all the numbers need to be displayled in a same way.
2. Or you can just use `\num[round-mode=places,group-separator={,},output-decimal-marker={.}]{\fpeval{1000 - 2000}}`